# Insert text from post with "

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to find out how to insert text to mysql that contains ' and "; I tried `mysqli_real_escape_string` and it just stops it all together, so that's out of the question. My current code insertion is

```
    public function SubmitReply() {
        $query = <<<SQL
        INSERT INTO {$this->tprefix}posts(guid,poster,content,postdate)
        VALUES(:guid,:poster,:content,:postdate)
SQL;
        $resource = $this->db->db->prepare( $query );
            $resource->execute( array (
            ':guid' => $_POST['guid'],
            ':poster'   => $_POST['poster'],
            ':content'  => htmlspecialchars($_POST['editor']),
            ':postdate' => $_POST['postdate'],
            ));
            print_r($_POST);
            print_r($_GET);
            return $resource->rowCount();
    }
```

And then it's read as

```
    public function LoadPosts() {
        echo "Under Development";
        $cnvtpc = str_replace("_", " ", $_GET['topic']);
        $query = <<<SQL
        SELECT poster,content,postdate
        FROM {$this->tprefix}posts 
        WHERE guid = :converted
SQL;
        $resource = $this->db->db->prepare( $query );
        $resource->execute( array (
        ':converted'    => $cnvtpc,
        ));
        foreach($resource as $row ) {
            echo '<tr><td class = "profile">'.self::TranslateToText($row['poster']).'</td><td class="content">'.htmlspecialchars_decode($row['content']).'</td><td class="details">Posted On '.$row['postdate'].'</td></tr>';
        }
    }
```

Now if someone posts something in it's fine, unless they want to post, 
`I'm using this code right now and it works great` which will then insert `I` and then the ' breaks the remaining insert.

Okay. I was able to get some more data that might be able to help show what the issue is.
My Post Output from Inserting a record with an apostrophe:

```
Array ( [process] => DEF_FORUM_SUBMIT_REPLY [guid] => Forum Rules [poster] => 1 [postdate] => 2015-10-21 01:36:07 [editor1] => [editor] =>
Let [#39;s_see_what_the_apostrophe_returns_in_post_

] => )
```

We see now that another POST variable has somehow been dynamically created. (Caught me by surprise, I have something I want to work on later that will depend on dynamic posts)
So the issue has been narrowed to the editor post is actually just `Let` here, whereas there's now a `$_POST['#39;s_see_what_the_apostrophe_returns_in_post_ (Some whitespace here)']` that has a value of nothing, so my ajax data is

```
data: $("#reply").serialize() + "&editor=" + textarea,
```

It's been fixed as far as entering the data goes, but now my ajax isn't working and it's redirecting.
Current code is

```
             <script>
$(function() {
  $('#reply').submit(function(event) {
    var $("#editor1").val() = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
    $.ajax({
      type: $("#reply").attr("method"),
      url: $("#reply").attr('action'),
      data: $("#reply").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $(".processing").html(data);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the form itself

```
<form id="reply" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="process" id="process" value="DEF_FORUM_SUBMIT_REPLY">
<input type="hidden" name="guid" id="guid" value="<?php DEF_TOPIC_NAME($_GET['topic']); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="poster" id="poster" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['key']['userid']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="postdate" id="postdate" value="<?php echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>">


            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
            <p style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px;">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Post Reply" id="submit_reply"></p>
            </form>
            <div class="processing"></div>
```

CKeditor is used hence the manually defining the value within the Javascript, because if you don't get it then it simply passes nothing in the post data.

Comment: That is really strange; PDO should auto-escape the quotes in bound parameters.

Comment: I thought so too, I'll try defining $_POST first and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @Amadan it does not escape anything

Comment: @MorganGreen are you sure that's what was received on server? How do you check it was insert improperly?

Comment: I thought one of the main bonuses of PDO was string escaping.

Comment: @MorganGreen it does not need to escape anything: the data is a parameter, it's just passed as is.

Comment: I did find the issue (it's declared up top) but fixing that issue opened a new one.

Comment: Seems the issue lies in ` //$("#editor1").val() = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();` after my onsubmit, but I've also tried ` //var $("#editor1").val() = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();` and it also breaks the ajax call, so I'm not sure what else to try

Comment: `var $("#editor1").val() = ` --- what's that? o_O